# How to open new tab in existing terminal instead of new terminal instance?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> in Ubuntu 18.04, a new terminal instance is opened. Is there a way to tweak the shortcut so if a terminal instance is already opened, then it just gets focused and a new tab is opened?

I'm tired of having 100 terminals opened because of my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> habit.

I'm using hyper terminal, but something working with gnome-terminal would be a good start!

Comment: Please use animated gifs only to add value to a question or answer.

Comment: I removed that ;-)

Comment: @vanadium I don't know when, but this has apparently been fixed.  Entering `gnome-terminal --tab` in a terminal in 18.10 does in fact, open a new terminal for me.

Comment: @Charles Green Indeed it does when you run the command in gnome-terminal. However, it does not behave this way if you launch the command or a script containing the command with a hotkey.

Answer (score 3):

Use **Tilix** !

You can set the behaviour in the Preferences -> Global:

[image: on new instance setting]

---

Screenshot from [Tilix website](https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/):

[image: Tilix]]

Comment: This is nice but a shame it doesn't focus the existing window frame if it's on a different workspace.